# Save a list of objects mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following object:

```
public class CarModelList
{
    public List<CarModel> CarsList { get; set; }
}
```

The CarModel is as follows:

```
public class CarModel
{
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Color { get; set; }

        public List<SelectItem> ColorList { get; set; }

        public string Seats { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }

        public string Year { get; set; }

}
```

I have a view which on loading first displays 3 `checkboxes` : Sea, Air, Soil.
If one `checkbox` is checked a tab is shown with the `CarModel` properties.
Depending on the checkboxes checked(Sea, Air or Soil), different `CarModel` properties will be displayed.  For eg, if Air is checked the Seats will not be shown 
or if Sea is checked the  Model is not shown.
The properties of the different `CarModel` ar shown in tabs. So if Sea is checked then the CarModel properties will be displayed in a tab excluding the Model property.
Then when Air is checked another tab is open to display the properties of the `CarModel` excluding the Seats property.
In my view I have only one submit button to save the `CarModel`.
So I thought of creating a Model containing a list of CarModel for the display and saving.  Thus upon checking a new checkbox, the new CarModel is added to the list, `CarModelList`.
Any idea of how to proceed with the saving and `validation` of this `CarModelList`?

Comment: Instead of hiding/showing some properties of CarModel, better you create a car model for every type and display that type when checkbox is checked.

Comment: Oh so I have like 3 CarModels for each checkbox: Air, Sea and Soil?

Comment: What do you mean by tab? Can you share your HTMl code, then I can help you

Comment: 3 separate models (with `CarModelList` containing a property for each) would be the easiest for both model binding and validation.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Where do I initialize the 3 models then?  The first time the page is loaded, the model for Sea is initialized and the other two models (Air and Soil) are left at null.  Upon clicking on the Air checkbox,  I want to initialize the CarModel for Air.  How can I do that using JSON?

Comment: That depends. Probably making a ajax call to a method that initializes the model and returns the appropriate partial based on the checkbox would be appropriate.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Do you have an example of how to do this?

Comment: That is far too broad. You need to show far more information about what you are currently doing, in particular  your checkboxes and how you are creating the tabs etc