# Getting some property of an ajax success data and binding it to the view

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the following:

```
public class CarModelList
{
    public CarModel CarsSea { get; set; }
    public CarModel CarsAir { get; set; }
    public CarModel CarsSoil { get; set; }
}
```

The CarModel is as follows:

```
public class CarModel
{
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public string Color { get; set; }

        public List<SelectItem> ColorList { get; set; }

        public string Seats { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }

        public string Year { get; set; }

}
```

Upon clicking on some check box, a new CarModel, CarsAir, is added to CarModelList.  This is done using an ajax call:

```
var obj = $('#form0').serialize();
             var jsonObj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))
             console.log(jsonObj);
             $.ajax({
             url: "@Url.Action("AddAirModel", "Quote")",
             //contentType: "application/json",
             data: jsonObj,
             dataType: "json",
             type: "POST",
             success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 //data.appendTo("#AirQuote");
                 console.log(data.language);
                 $("#AirQuote").show();

             },
             error: function (jqXHR, statusText, errorText) {
                 alert('Error: ' + errorText)
             }
```

My action in the Controller is :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddAirModel(CarModelList listCars)
    {
        listCars.CarsAir = new CarModel();
        listCars.CarsAir.TypeOfService = "3";
        ConfigureViewModel(listCars.CarsAir);
        return Json(new { data = listCars }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This correctly add initializes the new CarsAir in the CarModelList and return the CarModelList listCars in the data.
However I now want to bind the CarsAir to the view.  I have the following:

```
    if (Model.QuoteModelAir != null)
    {
    <div id="AirQuote">
        <div>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuoteModelAir.Seats)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuoteModelAir.Seats)
        </div>
        ....so on for all the properties of CarsAir.

    </div>
    }
```

So how do I bind the data.CarsAir from the ajax results to the view?

Comment: You have to either: 1. return the View rendered by the server instead of the JSON data (Razor runs on the server, not on the client, you cannot "bind" from the client). 2. Use a framework like Angular/Vue/React. 3. Manually write the HTML. Choose the option that suits you best

Comment: Having a `CarModelList listCars` parameter in your POST method makes no sense - you are just posting back exactly the same model you just sent to the view. If this is a follow up to you [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132013/save-a-list-of-objects-mvc5) then you should be handling the `.click()` event of the checkbox, passing a value identifying which checkbox and then returning a partial view of the appropriate `CarModel`

Comment: @StephenMuecke :  What if I want to return it to the same view?

Comment: That is what an ajax call will do :). In you method you initialize a new `CarModelList` and within in that the appropriate `CarModel` based on which checkbox was clicked, then you return a partial view based on say `CarsSea`, then you add it to the DOM in the success callback (i.e `$(someElement).html(data)`). And based on your previous question, the partial will contain the elements for the tab, so you will add it to the tab container (and you would remove it if the checkbox was later unchecked)

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Ok, so I have added a new CarModel to my list.  So how do I return a partial view with the model?

Comment: Create a partial view with `@model CarModelList` and use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CarsSea.Seats)` etc and then return that partial - `return PartialView("yourPartialName", model);` where `model` is your instance of `CarModelList`

Comment: @StephenMuecke :) This is not what I wanted to know.  Sorry I did not ask my question properly.  Can I still do an Ajax call to the controller and then return a partial view?  And also can I have different partial views and a single submit button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174168/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tabby).